# Set Cocoon to only add new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

I've been searching all over and I can't find a definitive way to make it so that Cocoon will only add new records and not show existing records of a model that I am trying to add to.

**Model Setup**

```
Order
belongs_to :property
has_many :deeds, through :property 

Property
has_many :orders
has_many :deeds

Deed
belongs_to :property
```

When trying to add a `Deed` from the `order` page to an existing `property`, I set the form to `@properties` with `fields_for :deeds` and all works as expected. However, it shows all existing `deeds` which I fully understand why it does but I would like to make it so that it only allows the **addition of new deeds**. Is there any concise way of doing this?

**Bonus:**

If the above is doable, is there a way to make it so that it would show the existing deeds with said `order_id` other than having to create 2 separate partials with corresponding view logic?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if cocoon is the right tool for what you are asking, since cocoon helps in building a complete form with nested items. Of course you could just `hide` existing items, or make them un-editable. But if you only need to add a new nested item, you could just only add a single item? No? (e.g. show the `new` form of a deed in a model and prefill the order-id? Which seems much simpler in this case?

Comment: It would be simpler but I need to be able to add an unlimited amount of deeds to the property via the order page. So cocoon works perfectly for my needs in all ways except that it shows existing deeds on a property. I guess I could try to hide existing ones some how, well thanks for your response @nathanvda

Comment: You can easily check if the current object is new or already existed using `f.object.new_record?` assuming `f` is your form/partial object and then set a class or display property accordingly.

Comment: @nathanvda oh right! That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for now that I've tested it. I'm somewhat new to Rails and especially form manipulation so thank you for taking the time to respond!